# Need guidance on correct routing my laravel app

Tags: php, laravel

Im making a festival-app in Laravel, and it can have more festivals, wich are stored in the db as a festivals-table.

When user is working on one festival, ive set it so he is on the route:
festival/festival-slug-name/

And if something needs doing, like creating a band, it is
festival/festival-slug-name/create-band

Its working fine, but im not sure this is the best way. Because I have to make it like this in the controller (FisController):

```
public function festivalCreateBand($slugname) {
    $fest = DB::table('fs_festivals')->where('slug', $slugname)->first();
    return View::make('fis.create-band')->with('festival', $fest);
}
```

and this in the route:

```
    Route::get('/festival/{slugname}/create-band', array(
        'as' => 'fis-band-create',
        'uses' => 'FisController@festivalCreateBand'
        )
);
```

... so user could add a band to the specific festival.
Later on I will add relations between bands and artists, and such, and wanted to get this right before i add more stuff.

Im sure there is an more elegant way to this, or another approach. Should i maybe store a WorkingOnWichFestival or something in the users session, that changes if he selects a different festival. Am I doing it correct? Or is it another approach?

Answer (score 0):

My solution here was to use Session to store the current-working-festival-id, and then retrieving it in the controllers before the views that needs it.